# Need to call ViewModal Method from Model Class using knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js

I need to save whole data at once every time when user click on single item. for that I used **subscribe()** for each property. 
But in my case I need to call parent **ApplySetting**() method from inside model function. I don't think its a good idea to pass List every time when fill the array. Because I have large number of data. Would you tell me, Is there any best way to do this please

```js
function UserViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.userID = data.userID;
  
  self.userroles = ko.observableArray();
  self.userroles.removeAll();
  
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    self.userroles.push(new UserRoleModal(item));
  });

  self.ApplySetting(data) {
    //Ajax POST method to send List to server
  }
}

function UserRoleModal(item) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.userID = ko.observable(item.Id);
  self.CanEdit = ko.observable(item.CanEdit);
  self.CanDelete = ko.observable(item.CanDelete);
  self.canView = ko.observable(item.canView);
  self.FullControl = ko.observable(item.FullControl);

  self.canView.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // need to call ApplySetting method and pass List
  });
  
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="panel-body text-center"> CanEdit</th>
      <th class="panel-body text-center"> CanDelete</th>
      <th class="panel-body text-center"> canView</th>
      <th class="panel-body text-center"> FullControl</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:userroles">
    <tr>
      <td class="panel-body text-center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: CanDelete' /></td>
      <td class="panel-body text-center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: canView' /></td>
      <td class="panel-body text-center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: FullControl' /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal use case for a `ko.pureComputed`. Knockout's computed values manage their own dependency tracking. I.e.: by using an observable value, you are automatically subscribed to any changes:

```
function UserRoleModal(item) {
  /* ... */

  self.viewOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return {
      canEdit: self.CanEdit(),
      canDelete: self.CanDelete(),
      canView: self.canView()
      fullControl: self.FullControl()
    };
  });

};
```

This property will be a plain object representation of your `UserRoleModal`'s state inside a subscribable. This means you can collect all roles in the parent view model and subscribe to post updates:

```
function UserViewModel(data) {
  /* ... */

  var userRoleSettings = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.userroles().map(function(role) {
     return role.viewOptions();
    });
  }).extend({ deferred: true });       

  userRoleSettings.subscribe(function applySetting(latestSettings) {
    //Ajax POST method to send List to server
  });
}
```

Summarized:

- Whenever a `RoleModal` permission property changes, `viewOptions` updates
- Whenever a `viewOptions` property changes, `userRoleSettings` updates
- Whenever `userRoleSettings` updates, `applySettings` is called with the latest value

Comment: superb!!!. well explained and I was manage to understand and implement it. very helpful. Thank you:)

Comment: Also tell me if I need to send single item to server, how I can send it using same approach?